# Does anybody know the file path for windows 10 action center

Tags: windows-10, action-center

I want to configure windows 10 **Action center**(which comes up with **Winkey + A**) to a touchpad gesture of my laptop.

[Windows 10 Action center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xu2kI.png)

My touchpad program allows me to configure its actions(launch different programs for different gestures) but I need to find out which .exe file in system32 directory is for the Action center. Does anybody have a clue? Thanks in advance.

*Ex: To launch windows calculator for a touchpad gesture, I would have to link to **"system32/calc.exe"***

Comment: I just find that the process C:\Windows\SystemApps\ShellExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\ShellExperienceHost.exe called file 
C:\Windows\ShellExperiences\Windows.UI.ActionCenter.dll for Action Center, not sure if it's what you would like to find. Also the shell commands to open Actions center could run "ms-actioncenter:"

Comment: I don’t the location of Action Center, even don’t know the .exe file name of it. 
But, we can create a shortcut to the Action Center. What about linking the shortcut to your touchpad program, if your touchpad program can launch the shortcut, shortcut will launch Action Center.

Comment: @KateLi between yours and hanjo's answers i was able to link to action center to my touchpad. Thanks

Comment: @Origami "But, we can create a `shortcut` to the Action Center". Are you referring to the same method as KateLi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find an "executable" as such, but the action center can be opened through the URI `ms-actioncenter:`. You can type that for instance in the Run box and it will open the action center.

If you would like to have an "application" that you can launch, I would suggest to create a file with the following content:

```
start ms-actioncenter:
```

and save this as e.g. `actioncenter.bat`. When you run this the action center should appear. You may be annoyed by the cmd prompt that is starting every time as well. For that you can use a tiny utility called [RunHiddenConsole](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/attachments/660/RunHiddenConsole.zip) and just execute `runhiddenconsole.exe actioncenter.bat`